# How to determine where selected row is closed or open on itemClick event in AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have an AdvancedDataGrid with Hierarchical data in it. On itemClick I have to identify if the row I clicked is expanded or collapsed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AdvancedDataGrid has a member function isItemOpen(item:Object):Boolean.  Pass it the data for the row and it will return true if the item is open, false otherwise.